# Providing a pointer to a function for a C callback in Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, header, translation

I'm trying to convert the following C headers to equivalent Delphi versions:

```
/** pointer to a malloc function, supporting client overriding memory
 *  allocation routines */
typedef void * (*yajl_malloc_func)(void *ctx, unsigned int sz);

/** pointer to a free function, supporting client overriding memory
 *  allocation routines */
typedef void (*yajl_free_func)(void *ctx, void * ptr);

/** pointer to a realloc function which can resize an allocation. */
typedef void * (*yajl_realloc_func)(void *ctx, void * ptr, unsigned int sz);

typedef struct
    {
        /** pointer to a function that can allocate uninitialized memory */
        yajl_malloc_func malloc;
        /** pointer to a function that can resize memory allocations */
        yajl_realloc_func realloc;
        /** pointer to a function that can free memory allocated using
         *  reallocFunction or mallocFunction */
        yajl_free_func free;
        /** a context pointer that will be passed to above allocation routines */
        void * ctx;
    } yajl_alloc_funcs;
```

My Delphi code looks like this at the moment:

```
  Tyajl_malloc_func = function(context: pointer; sizeOf: Cardinal): Pointer of Object; cdecl;

  Tyajl_free_func = procedure(context: pointer; ptr: Pointer) of Object; cdecl;

  Tyajl_realloc_func = function(context: pointer; ptr: Pointer; sizeOf: cardinal): Pointer of Object; cdecl;
  yajl_alloc_funcs = record
    malloc: Tyajl_malloc_func;
    free: Tyajl_free_func;
    realloc: Tyajl_realloc_func;
    ctx: pointer;
  end;
```

The problem is that I'm pretty sure I'm treating these incorrectly as I'm unable to remember how to obtain a Pointer to the two functions. My question is: How can I obtain a pointer to the malloc function when I try to assign it to the yajl_alloc_funcs.malloc for example?

Alternatively, if I'm doing something very wrong in my translation, what is the "proper" approach here?

**Update:** There appears to be some confusion over what I'm asking. I have implemented actual methods and am trying to supply them to the DLL using the afore-pasted record using the following code:

```
var
   alloc_funcs: yajl_alloc_funcs;
begin
   FillChar(alloc_funcs, SizeOf(alloc_funcs), #0);
   alloc_funcs.malloc := yajl_malloc;
   alloc_funcs.free := yajl_free;
   alloc_funcs.realloc := yajl_realloc;
..
```

Which gives me an error of:
*E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'*
Which I suspect to be because I've done something wrong in my header translation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conversion *from* C *to* Delphi? You better rewrite the logic...

Comment: @ring0 - I'm not sure I see your point, where is the logic problem?

Comment: @ring0  you have not understood the question

Comment: What? Use C functions in Delphi via their headers... including `malloc()`?

Comment: @ring0  No!  This C library is to be called from Delphi.  My guess is that is in the form of a DLL.  The OP has C header files and needs to translate function prototypes from C to Delphi.  This bit of code is to allow the library's client to supply their own memory allocation routines.

Comment: @ring0: I think you're slightly confused about the purpose of the code. I'm providing external methods to a C dll which allows you to supply your own Memory alloc methods.

Comment: - oh you want a hamburger? - No I tell you I want a hamburger :-)

Comment: @jamiei remove the of object and you should be good to go. Implementing malloc etc is not trivial because of the corner cases. Why do you want to supply your own memory allocation rather than use default?

Comment: @David Heffernan: I have removed the of Object and now get "E2009 Incompatible types: 'regular procedure and method pointer'".

Comment: If the type definition for the procedure types doesn't include of object then I guess your malloc must be a method rather than a free function.  What's the definition of your malloc?  Finally, WHY do you need to override the default malloc provided by the library?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use "of Object" - it is irrelevant here.

---

**Update:** Which line of code gives you an error? I can't imagine it, the next code compiles and works as expected:

```
type
  Tyajl_malloc_func = function(context: pointer; sizeOf: Cardinal): Pointer; cdecl;
  Tyajl_free_func = procedure(context: pointer; ptr: Pointer); cdecl;
  Tyajl_realloc_func = function(context: pointer; ptr: Pointer; sizeOf: cardinal): Pointer; cdecl;

  Tyajl_alloc_funcs = record
    malloc: Tyajl_malloc_func;
    free: Tyajl_free_func;
    realloc: Tyajl_realloc_func;
    ctx: pointer;
  end;

function yajl_malloc_func(context: pointer; sizeOf: Cardinal): Pointer; cdecl;
begin
  Result:= Pointer($1234);
end;

var
  yajl_alloc_funcs: Tyajl_alloc_funcs;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  yajl_alloc_funcs.malloc:= yajl_malloc_func;
  ShowMessage(Format('%p', [yajl_alloc_funcs.malloc(nil, 0)]));
end;
```

Comment: The line assigning the function to the record. I get an incompatible types, Cardinal and Pointer error.

Answer (score 0):

You now need to define functions called malloc free and realloc which you pass to this C library.  You can implement them in Delphi by calling GetMem, FreeMem and ReallocMem.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The problem isn't with the implementation of the functions but I think with the translation of the headers.

Comment: This code allows you to override the memory allocation in the C library.  if you want to do this then you need to supply malloc, free etc.  If you don't want to do this then you can likely just ignore this.  Serg is correct, of object is a mistake since these are free functions not instance methods.

Comment: Thanks David, I realise what they're for and have the implementations already elsewhere but am having problems using the translated headers which is where I think my problem is.

Comment: @jamiei sounds like you need to come back with a more precisely formulated question